# Perl object inside the same module

Tags: perl, oop, object

The title is vague but I'll explain it.

I have a Perl script which uses a module named `systemId`

I create an object inside the script

```
my $id = systemId->new({_dom => "dev"});
```

I am planning to instantiate an object similar to the one above but inside the systemId.pm.

How do I do that?

I can't really search it on the net as I do not know what to search to begin with.

Comment: Are you saying you want a new `systemId` object within `$id`? Everything depends on what is in `systemId.pm`, what you want to do with this internal object, and how you want to initialise it. Please show `systemId.pm` and write some Perl code that shows how you would like to use it with an internal secondary object. By the way classes must begin with a capital letter, so your `systemId.pm` should be `SystemId.pm` and start with `package SystemId`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can be done the same way it's done in a script. Similarly to how you can put the package and `main::` in the same file, you can use the class in the package file once it is defined.  See comments after code.

File **Play.pm**

```
package Play;    
use warnings;
use strict;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = { _data => shift || 'default' }; 
    bless $self, $class;
    print "New object created.\n";
    return $self;
}

sub data {
    my $self = shift;
    if (@_) { $self->{_data} = shift }
    return $self->{_data};
}

print "Inside the package. Create object.\n";
my $obj = Play->new();
my $data = $obj->data();
print "data: $data\n";
print "\n";

1;
```

The script

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Play;

print "In main\n";
my $obj = Play->new(25);
print "data: " . $obj->data() . "\n";
```

Printout when running the script

```
Inside the package. Create object.
New object created.
data: default

In main
New object created.
data: 25
```

Once the `bless` call executed then `$self` is an object of the class `Play`. From [bless](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html)

> bless REF,CLASSNAME
>       bless REF
>       This function tells the thingy referenced by REF that it is now an object in the CLASSNAME package. If CLASSNAME is omitted, the current package is used. [...]

Since we are right in the package it can be used as an object and methods called on it. From [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html)

> Once we've blessed the hash referred to by `$self` we can start calling methods on it.

This refers to working with `$self` hashref, which became the object.

Note that there may be issues of initialization when it comes to creating an object and the questions of what exactly is being done and how may be important.

---

I can't help it but ask, what do you want to do with this?

Comment: What if I create the object inside sub prn?

Comment: @BashingPerl  You are pushing it, aren't you :).  I don't see a reason why not, we're in the scope and `bless`-ing has happened.  Just don't call _that_ method.  Interesting to try ... tried, it works as expected.  Calling the method itself (inside of itself) is accepted and runs, and goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: I don't see how you can speculate what code is in `systemId.pm`, and how the initialisation data is supposed to work for the secondary object

Comment: @Borodin  Oh, right. Thank you. Removing that comment. I think it that it is still OK the create an object in the package, after all code for the class has been seen ...?

Comment: @BashingPerl  I have to correct my response to "_create object inside sub pm_" -- depending on how the initialization is done, per Borodin's comment. If `$self` is fully initialized in the constructor, then you may use it. However, that is not always the case and the initialization process can be arbitrarily  convoluted and complex. So I'd say that that would indeed be pushing it.  In fact, creating the object at any time before all package code has been seen may be troubling. I have removed that comment from my post.

Comment: @Borodin Sorry to bother you, I don't understand.  I meant: is it OK to create an object at the end of the package file, after all other code, right before the return (the `1;`).  I don't see why not (but then I don't know how Perl's OO works inside).

Comment: @zdim: Ah, do you mean that the module code has been compiled? What I understood was that you thought the OP had shown the source of the module. When your main code does `use Play` it will compile and execute all of `Play.pm`. That means the `print` statements will be executed, `$obj` and `$data` will be created and defined, and then they are discarded when the compiler reaches the end of the file. Sometimes a `print` statement can be useful, and you could define `our` variables (but don't do that). A module is only for defining values -- mostly subroutines -- for use in other files

Comment: @zdim: So yes, you may create an object at the end of the module file, but it's of very little use as it will be discarded as soon as the `use` in the main code is compiled

Comment: @Borodin  Yes, that is what I meant, sorry. (That _code seen_ is probably from C++ use, where in related situations may matter whether a piece of code has already _been seen_ by the comiler for some following statement to be at least allowed.)

Comment: @Borodin I don't know how Perl compiles a class from the package file -- when it builds code to run ("opcodes"?) and in what order. May it know to wait with instantiating an object inside package until the whole class is compiled? The `$self` _may_ use methods not "seen" yet, defined after it in the source (after bless's `;` or after constructor's last `}`, I guess). As the code in package runs only when loaded in another file, perhaps an object may be created anywhere in package source? This is what I meant under "_been seen_".  I guess it does come down to initialization, as you say.

Answer (score 3):

As easy as:

```
my $id = systemId->new({_dom => "dev"});
```

You may also use...

```
my $id = __PACKAGE__->new({_dom => "dev"});
```

...but the first one is more obvious.

A new object instance could be created everwhere, including the package/class itself.

The `->new` function is typically:

```
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = bless {@_}, $class;
    return $self;
}
```

The instance is actually created in the class module itself (using `bless`). There is no magic in `->new` in Perl, some modules also use another name, see [`DateTime`'s](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) `->now` which does `->new(epoch => time)` internally.